# Linux can only connect to AP with static IP, has no Internet connectivity (not a router issue)

Tags: dhcp, ping, internet, access-point, wicd

A Linux laptop can only connect to its AP with a static IP. Once connected it can’t ping any local or external IP.

The router has no issue with any other device.

I have tried restarting DHCP, rebooting, etc. Wicd is being used to manage the connection.

The result is the same on both wireless and wired.

The MAC is not blacklisted and changing it has no effect. Since I can’t ping IPs it’s not a DNS issue.

What can I do to troubleshoot further?

Comment: What distribution and version? What is the output of `ip addr`?

Comment: That looks like it's not getting any DHCP response. Debug with `wireshark`, `tcpdump` or `dhcpdump`. Look at the syslog for what your DHCP client says. Stop DHCP client, and run it manually to see what happens.

Comment: @fpmurphy It’s an Ubuntu fork called elementary OS. The output of ip addr is BROADCAST, MULTI, LOWER_UP mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000 link/ether (some IPv6 address) inet (the local static IP)/24 brd (net mask) scope global wlan1 valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Comment: @dirkt Thanks. Stopping and starting DHCP didn’t have any obvious impact. I will try to take the other suggestions but those tools aren’t installed and since it is bricked from the Internet installing them may be difficult (but not impossible if I can get the dependencies onto an external drive).

Comment: @dirkt  Ah, I actually do have tcpdump but when I run it even with sudo it says “getifaddrs: permission denied” (I  may need to RTFM on it).

Comment: Update: I can ping 127.0.0.1 but not the router. I verified that all symptoms are the same if I try to connect to a mobile hotspot. Also noticed netplan is in use.

Comment: All the symptoms you describe say "this interface didn't get an address". Debug to find out why it doesn't get one with DHCP. Also, if you know the IP address range etc. for your network, you can manually set an address, netmask and default with `ip addr` and `ip route`, and see if that works at least.

Comment: @dirkt Thanks. I can set a static IP etc and get it to claim it’s connected but it can’t ping and ip route returns `192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.213`. I don’t really know how to debug or troubleshoot it further, beyond just playing with nmcli, nmtui, and netplan to no avail.